# Swift API Call Decoding Issue: decoding error

Tags: swift, decoding, openai-api

Last week I made a chatGpt application using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bUDCW2NeO8Y . It worked just fine, but when I started working on it again today it didn't work. This uses the [OpenAISwift](https://swiftpackageindex.com/adamrushy/OpenAISwift) package.

After 'debugging' it a bit I got this error:

> failure(OpenAISwift.OpenAIError.decodingError(error:
> Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "object",
> intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [],
> debugDescription: "No value associated with key
> CodingKeys(stringValue: "object", intValue: nil) ("object").",
> underlyingError: nil))))

The code I use is almost the same as in the video, the only difference is that I trim white spaces and new lines (this isn't the issue I checked)

My code (that has the error) looks like this:

```
import OpenAISwift
import SwiftUI    
final class ViewModel: ObservableObject{
    init(){}
    
    private var client: OpenAISwift?
    
    func setup(){
        client = OpenAISwift(authToken: "MY_API_KEY")
    }
    
    func makeCall(text: String,
                  completion: @escaping (String) -> Void){
        client?.sendCompletion(with: text,
                               maxTokens: 500,
                               completionHandler: { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let model):
                let output = model.choices.first?.text.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) ?? ""
                completion(output)
            case .failure:
                print("Failed: \(result)")
                break
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I hope someone could help me with this, because everything I have tried failed. I tried using other methods of calling the API but that also wouldn't work...
So if you know what the issue is and how to fix it please let me know

Edit sendCompletion code:

```
public func sendCompletion(with prompt: String, model: OpenAIModelType = .gpt3(.davinci), maxTokens: Int = 16, temperature: Double = 1, completionHandler: @escaping (Result<OpenAI<TextResult>, OpenAIError>) -> Void) {
    let endpoint = Endpoint.completions
    let body = Command(prompt: prompt, model: model.modelName, maxTokens: maxTokens, temperature: temperature)
    let request = prepareRequest(endpoint, body: body)

makeRequest(request: request) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let success):
        do {
            let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(OpenAI<TextResult>.self, from: success)
            completionHandler(.success(res))
        } catch {
            completionHandler(.failure(.decodingError(error: error)))
        }
    case .failure(let failure):
        completionHandler(.failure(.genericError(error: failure)))
    }
}
```

}

Edit after feedback:

I updated the version, and after this it stopped giving me that error, but it now gives me a different one.... this one:

> success(OpenAISwift.OpenAI<OpenAISwift.TextResult>(object: nil, model:
> nil, choices: nil, usage: nil, data: nil))

Comment: The error is about decoding json but the code you have posted has nothing to do with decoding json.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, I accidentally pressed enter when I made that title. I changed it as fast as possible.

Comment: What would help then? Because this is where it goes wrong

Comment: `sendCompletion(with:maxTokens:completionHandler:)` where there is I guess, a visible `JSONDecoder` with a `(De)Codable` model, or hidden with Alamofire with `responseDecodable(of:)`, and where you get the real output of the API would greatly help!. Currently, it's like saying there is a leak in the kitchen, but showing only the front of the house and asking what could be done to be fixed.

Comment: @Larme I edited it containing the sendCompletion code

Comment: I guess you enter `completionHandler(.failure(.decodingError(error: error)))`? If `success` is `Data`, as I guess, do `print("Response received: \(String(data: success, encoding: .utf8)")` I guess the response isn't the one you expect

Comment: @Larme, so there is nothing I can do?

Comment: Print the response you are getting and share the output. It seems you got a different response JSON. Why? I don't know. Could be an update on the back-end, do you use the last version of the lib?

Comment: @Larme I cant type / edit the file its from...

Comment: OpenAI strongly recommends developers of client-side applications proxy requests through a separate backend service to keep their API key safe. API keys can access and manipulate customer billing, usage, and organizational data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example code, works well for me, **if** your `YOUR-APIKEY` is valid. Let me know if this does not work for you.

**Note**, use the latest `main` branch of `OpenAISwift`, not other versions or tags.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import OpenAISwift


@MainActor
class OpenAIModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var answers = [String]()
    
    let client: OpenAISwift
    
    init() {
        client = OpenAISwift(authToken: "YOUR-APIKEY")
    }
    
    func ask(text: String) async {
        do {
            let result = try await client.sendCompletion(
                with: text,
                model: .gpt3(.davinci),
                maxTokens: 500,
                temperature: 1
            )
            let output = result.choices?.first?.text ?? "no answer"
            answers.append(output)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    func makeCall(text: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
        client.sendCompletion(with: text, maxTokens: 500) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let model):
                let output = model.choices?.first?.text.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) ?? ""
                completion(output)
            case .failure:
                print("---> Failed: \(result)")
                completion("Failed")
                break
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var openAI = OpenAIModel()
    let text = "explain Schrödinger's wave equation"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("fetching...")
            ForEach(openAI.answers, id: \.self) { answer in
                Text(answer)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            openAI.makeCall(text: text){ answer in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    openAI.answers.append(answer)
                }
            }
        }
//        .task{
//            await openAI.ask(text: text)
//        }
    }
}
```

Note also, there is an issue reported at: https://github.com/adamrushy/OpenAISwift/issues/28 regarding a bug in decoding, it may be relevant to your case.

Comment: I used your MakeCall, but with this and my own code after the update I get this error: success(OpenAISwift.OpenAI<OpenAISwift.TextResult>(object: nil, model: nil, choices: nil, usage: nil, data: nil))

Comment: And as a question about your code, you make the ask function but you never use it... because it's commented out. is this function needed?

Comment: ok, re your first comment, my code works well for me when there is a `valid` api key.
 I suspect you must have other code that is not correct, and thus giving you some errors.
 Try my code as is, and let me know if it works. Re, your second comment, using `ask()` is to show an alternative
 way of doing all this using the newer Swift concurrency (async/await), that is why it is commented.
 Use one or the other.  What input `text` to `makeCall` did your try?

Comment: I used all your code, I don't think it works for me because it only says fetching.... I used a VALID api key so where should I check it messing up? With thee ask function it adds "No answer"

Comment: you have to wait for the answer to arrive. Try my code again please.

Comment: I will wait, in these past 5 minutes it still hasnt shown up, and when I tried debugging it using the print(result) I got the same error as with my own code, the OpenAI<TextResult>(object: nil, model: nil, choices: nil, usage: nil, data: nil)

Comment: it should ony take 5-10 seconds. Cannot see how it is not working for you with just my code.

Comment: The main issue is that I only get nil. I remade a api key so it should work, but it still gives back nil. So idk how to fix this. I think the problem isn't with you code, but what the problem is idk...

Comment: a new key, for `gpt3` is that correct, not `gpt4`

Comment: yes gpt3, I used this link https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys

Comment: cannot see what the problem is. I also generated a new key, and that works as well.

Comment: Note, ensure that you have ticked the `Outgoing Connections (client)`
 in the `App Sandbox` in `Signing & Capabilities`.

Comment: After some working on it, it decided to work. So ill make this the answer. Thank you