# Integrating ChatGPT into SwiftUI Application

Tags: swift, swiftui, openai-api, chatgpt-api

When I click the send button after entering my input, there is no response from ChatGPT API. I am not sure what is causing this please take a look and see what is missing (I have actually added my API Key but in the code below I have not provided it for privacy reasons. Here is the package dependency I used: https://github.com/adamrushy/openAISwift

```swift
import OpenAISwift
import SwiftUI

final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    init() {}
    
    private var client: OpenAISwift?
    
    func setup() {
        client = OpenAISwift(authToken:
                                "MY API KEY")
    }

    func send(text: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
        client?.sendCompletion(with: text,
                               maxTokens: 500,
                               completionHandler: {result in
            switch result{
            case .success(let model):
                let output = model.choices?.first?.text ?? ""
                completion(output)
            case .failure:
                break
            }            
        })        
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    @State var text = ""
    @State var models = [String]()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ForEach(models, id: \.self) { string in
                Text(string)
            }
            Spacer()
            
            HStack{
                TextField("Type here", text: $text)
                Button("Send") {
                    send()
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.setup()
        }
        .padding()
    }

    func send() {
        guard !text.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty else {
            return
        }
        models.append("Me: \(text)")
        viewModel.send(text: text) {response in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.models.append("FX-01: "+response)
                self.text = ""
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `@ObservedObject` in the `View` that owns the object. Use `@StateObject`

Comment: Ok, however there is still no response from ChatGPT API

Comment: What debugging have you done? Is your `send` function being called in `ViewModel`? Is `client` non-nil? Is the completion handler called? What is `result` (success or failure)?

Comment: The send function is being called from the Button in the ContentView struct.  the send function is not being called from the ViewModel, It is being called directly from the ContentView struct.

Comment: There was an SO question a couple of days ago that said that this package was throwing an error. Not sure it applies but there is supposed to be an issue on their git. Also this API breaks OpenAPI recommendations by putting the API key in the client side project.

Comment: There is no specific debugging implemented in the code ( logging or debugging )

Comment: Ideas of what to do, would this code not work with their package dependency then?

Comment: I implemented just like the OpenAPI website says. I used Firebase Functions as my server less endpoint and the curl

Comment: What package dependency should i use instead then and could you please send a link to the Github

Comment: I didn’t use any package, look at the open api documentation you just follow their samples

Comment: Can you please provide me some code or show me in swift how I would code very simply way to integrate Chatgpt using API in Xcode swiftUI application (I am new to swift so this would greatly help and be appreciated)

Comment: @AlexandrosEghoyan You didn't answer most of my debugging questions. You did answer that the `ViewModel send` function is being called, but you didn't answer the rest of my questions about what happens when it is called. So I repeat, Is `client` non-nil? Is the completion handler called? What is `result` (success or failure)? Use the debugger and trace through the code. See what happens, report the results in your question.

Comment: ChatGPT communication does not belong in Swift, I don't have a sample because your API key does not belong inside an iOS App. My setup consists of a Firebase Function that uses `axios` to make a call to OpenAI, then I access the Function via the Firebase API.

Comment: No, client could be nil when send(text:completion:) is called, but the method handles this safely using optional chaining. Yes, the completion handler is called when client?.sendCompletion returns a result, regardless of whether it's a success or failure. If it's a success, the generated text is passed to the completion closure. The result is a success I check with this by by adding print statements "S" and "F" to the switch cases for success and failure, (I will use debugger now give me a minute)

Comment: I used Breakpoints to test but there was no output in the debugger output

Comment: @AlexandrosEghoyan Your last big comment doesn't answer any of my questions. We can all read your code and see what it is supposed to do so describing it doesn't help. What matters is what really happens when you run the code. Your most recent comment isn't clear. We don't know what breakpoints you set or what you tried to see. Put a breakpoint on the `client?.sendCompletion(with: text,` line. When it stops (if it does), check if `client` is nil or not. Then put a breakpoint on `switch result{` and see what `result` is. If neither breakpoint is called then `send` isn't even being called.

Comment: have a look at this SO post answer, that sends a request to OpenAI, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75928704/swift-api-call-decoding-issue-decoding-error/75929723  also note that if your rate limit has expired, you can get a response with nil. Let me know if the answer does not work for you.

Comment: Note, I tested your code, and all works well for me with my key. **Note** this `issue` https://github.com/adamrushy/OpenAISwift/issues/71  about the  rate limit has expired returning a `OpenAI<TextResult>(object: nil, model: nil, choices: nil, usage: nil, data: nil)`